# Modify XML Elements value using PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

In PHP I need to modify the element names of xml file so that if `EventName` is `308`, it should modify the value for `Host`/`Eventname` and `Eventtype` field.

```
<Report>
    <Data>
        <Event>
            <Host>LTE</Host>
            <EventName>308</EventName>
            <EventType>Attach Procedure</EventType>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <Host>LTE</Host>
            <EventName>302</EventName>
            <EventType>Attach Procedure</EventType>
        </Event>
    </Data>
</Report>
```

Since I am new to this, so I tried using `Simplexml` but no success.

Added non working code:

```
foreach($xml->Eventname as $node) {
    if((string)$node == '308') {
        $node->Eventname = 'Test';
        $node->EventType = 'Test2';          
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add your PHP code (even if it's not working) to your question and someone might be able to help

Comment: Well your first problem is that this loop isn't going to actually do anything: `foreach($xml->Eventname as $node)` - `$xml` presumably represents the root node, `<Report>`, which has no children called `Eventname`. It has some grand-children called `Event` (`foreach ( $xml->Data->Event as $node )`) each of which has a child called `EventName` (`$node->EventName`). Try to get one part of the code working before moving onto the next.